# Why is setting the variable to an empty string not needed in my code?

Tags: python, input

I'm new to coding and I'm creating a simple program that asks for your name and age. After playing around with the code for a bit in an attempt to simplify it, I've noticed that I don't need to set the `my_name` variable to an empty string before the while loop. Why is this the case?

(In the code below I've included the empty string, but if it is removed it does not impact the execution of the program.)

```
# Asks the user for their name and age
from checks import num_existing

my_name = ''
print("Hello, what is your name?")
my_name = input('>')

while not my_name or num_existing(my_name):
    print('Sorry, I do not understand. Please tell me your name again.')
    my_name = input('>')
else:
    print(f"It's nice to meet you {my_name}!")

age = input("What is your age? ")
print(f"You will be {int(age)+1} in a year.")
```

Comment: Why would it be needed?

Comment: Stuff doesn't need a reason to be unnecessary. Things are unnecessary by default. It doesn't make much sense to ask why something is unnecessary without additional context, like "this thing was necessary in this situation, but not this other one - what reason made it necessary in the first situation that didn't apply in the second?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @user2357112, why is it needed?

This line:

```
my_name = input('>')
```

Already creates a new variable, with the input string as the value, the empty string assignment is useless, when you assign an empty string before the input, only thing the input does is to override the original empty string variable and make it inaccessible.